# fetch current location in activity's onConnected method and then display the same on child fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am fetching the current location of the user in the `ActionbarActivity` in the `onConnected` method as doing the same in `onCreate` method give me map initialization error.
I am successfully able to fetch the location in Activity, but now facing issues in displaying the same on the child fragments of this activity.
Any help would he be appreciated....

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        getPickupAddress();
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");
    }
```

this method fetches the current location and stores it in string .

**Fragment.java**

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView");

            final View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

final TextView tx1 =(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.address);
```

How do I set the text of this textview above as the current location from the MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You can get address from your `MainActivity` as `String` and then call following in `Fragment`

```
String address = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getPickupAddress();
tx1.setText(address);
```

If `getPickupAddress()` is asynchronous, you can create and interface like

```
public interface MyLocationListener {
    public void onLocationReady(final String address);
}
```

In `Fragment` `onCreateView` you add call `((MainActivity) getActivity()).addLocationListener(this);`

This means that the `Fragment` must implement `MyLocationListener` interface. You can have an `ArrayList` of `MyLocationListener` in your `MainActivity` which then calls `onLocationReady` for all listeners when the location is got and removes listeners from the list as well.

Comment: getPickupAddress() return nothing.It makes a call to a method which runs Asynctask to fetch the location and then store the location in a global string of the activity.
Your solution would get me a CastException.
Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I updated my answer to give you idea how to handle async way. If MainActivity is not the Activity of Fragment, you could have a separate class which fetches the location and then notifies all listeners and passes the address to them. Static class could be useful here.

Comment: MainActivity is indeed the activity of the fragments.I will try the same with interface and let you know if i was able to accomplish.
thanks for the help Niko.Appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, if you get some problems, please let me know so I can help figure them out.